# wiring a ceiling light fitting

Tags: wiring, ceiling, light

I have 3 black wires - 3 green and 3 red - but when I attach to light fitting - light comes on with switch off and when I switch it on it blows any ideas ?

Comment: Some more information is needed.  Is this a new installation or is this an existing installation that you are changing? Are there more than one switch feeding this fixture?

Answer (score 1):

Because wires are not color-coded for installer benefit.   The wires are red and black, **because manufactured cable is red and black**. Actually the wires have a variety of functions.

The wires from supply are "always-hot" (red) and "neutral" (black).

The wires to the switch are "always-hot" (black) and "switched-hot" (red).  The switch will *short out* these two wires, that is its job, so connecting it to always-hot and neutral will always blow the fuse.

The wires to the lamp are "switched-hot" (red) and "neutral" (black).

The purposes don't match the colors.  I solve that with colored tape; say mark the switched-hot wires brown and the always-hots red. I always mark wires the same at both ends.  Once you color-code everything, *then* you match color to color.  It's the only way I work.  But you do you.